# Create Div Wrapper On 3rd Iteration Or When Query Loop Items Run Out

Tags: php, loop

I'm running into an issue.. I've written a code inside a loop so that it creates a new box every 3rd iteration in the loop. It does this nicely, however for example if I have 4 items in a full query of returned posts , it breaks on the 4th one because when it resets to 1 again (from creating the end div tags on the 3rd final iteration then it resets back to 1) it doesn't know to create and end to the 2nd box on the 4th post item. Is there a way so that if there is no more posts left in the query to create end div tag even there's only 1 left? If that makes sense..

```
<?php if($i%3 == 0){ ?>
<div id="featured-boxes">

<div class="itembox hightlighted-front" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemscope="">
    <h1 itemprop="name" class="icon-search-item">Featured Accident Lawyers</h1>

    <div class="itemboxinner">
        <div class="post clearfix">
<?php } ?>

            <?php /*echo "$i" . "<br>"; */?>
            <div class="thumbnail-large box-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="float: left;">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> <img
                itemprop="image" src="<?php echo $PPT->Image($post->ID, "url", "&amp;w=180&amp;h=128"); ?>" class="listImage"
                alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"/> </a>

                <div class="info"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
            </div>

            <?php $i++; ?>

<?php if($i%3 == 0) {  ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<?php } ?>

<?php if($i == 3){ ?><div class="clearfix"></div><?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place a single box opening and closing markup *outside* the loop, then only close/open a new one when it's every 3rd post and not last by using the built in loop vars `current_post` and `post_count`

```
if( ( ( $your_query->current_post + 1 ) % 3 == 0 )
    && ( $your_query->current_post + 1 ) != $your_query->post_count ){
        // close the box and open a new one.
}
```

EDIT - note that we add 1 to `current_post` in each test, as it starts at 0, not 1.